# Can only see MDNS packets when I look for DNS packets

Tags: wireshark, mdns

I'm playing with Wireshark and want to inspect some DNS packets so I flush my dns using `ipconfig /flushdns` and entering a url in my browser (Google Chrome). While I expect for a DNS packets and only get MDNS. What is that? How can I get the MDNS packets?

Comment: Could it be you have multiple interfaces (e.g. LAN, WiFi and LTE) and you are monitoring one while another is used for DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mDNS stands for multicast DNS, which is used for finding resources in local networks when a local DNS server isn't available, or isn't aware of a certain service. This is mostly used for Zero-configuration networking, when things like for example a Raspberry Pi running Octopi, then after boot the Octopi instance answers queries for `octopi.local`.

Why you're seeing these types of queries is hard to say without the actual Wireshark capture. But if you want to inspect DNS traffic, just use `nslookup` in a command prompt, it'll generate "normal" DNS traffic.

Further reading regarding [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) and [Zero-configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)